# I'm making a multiple choice quiz and can't figure out how to use loop to get Murillo answers from user before program ends or has error

Tags: python

More detail: program gives 3 answers and user has to pick one answer either you get it right and move on or wrong and you have to choose again. That's what I'm looking for after guessing/choosing wrong I wanna be able to choose again without program ending or giving me an error?

Comment: Hey there, have you had a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ?

Comment: Please edit your post, add the code you are having trouble with, and explain precisely the context and your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you

```
while(True):
    print "Enter Choice"
    print "1).Correct"
    print "2).Incorrect"
    print "3).Incorrect"
    choice = raw_input()
    if(choice == '1'):
        print "That's Correct"
        break
    else:
        print "Please Try Again"
```